# Surround HTML open and close tag pair with comments

Tags: java, regex, substitution, backreference

I need to write a java regex substitution (preferably purely declarative) that will do these analogous transformations:

1)

```
<a nonStandardAttrName="">Some visible text</a>
```

to

```
<span class="invalid"><a nonStandardAttrName=""></span>
Some visible text
<span class="invalid"></a></span>
```

and

2)

```
<b nonStandardAttrName="">Some visible text</a>
```

to

```
<span class="invalid"><b nonStandardAttrName=""></span>
Some visible text
<span class="invalid"></b></span>
```

3) etc. (i.e. the tag could be `a`, `b`, `foobar` - anything)

*(please don't propose a different approach - actually the app uses spans rather than comments but I must use this "suppress by surrounding the tags" approach that is not my design decision)*

Is it possible to do this with regular expressions? Matching the opening tag is easy because I can match the substring `nonStandardAttrName`, but how would I find the closing tag? Is there some kind of regular expression operation that says "whatever I captured earlier, look for that again later on"? If the tags were some finite set, I could hardcode those tag names in the regex but in my situation the tags could be a lot of non-standard tags. The closest thing I know of is substitution *backreferencing* - but that is only for output, not input.

**What I'm trying to do**

It's really not relevant, but my HTML parser will throw away markup that isn't standard HTML. But I need to preserve whatever quirky input the user has given me. So I need to escape it before parsing and unescape after parsing (by using comments or spans).

Comment: if <a> is recursive, you will have difficulty

Comment: Yes. I will either disable the transformation, or apply the transformation recursively on the inner HTML (which would make it programmatic rather than purely declarative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy actually. You can put backreferences in the input expression. Backreferences are not restricted to output substitution expressions.